# SQL Express remote access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

Is there any way to install SQL Express 2005 silently while configuring to allow remote access, or must the configuration be done with the SQL Server Management Studio UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the SQL Service is installed log into the database and run the following and then restart the SQL Service.

```
exec sp_configure 'remote access', 1
reconfigure
```

This will allow remote access to the service.  If you are installing a named instance you'll need to ensure that the SQL Browser service is running and set to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues is setting BROWSERSVCSTARTUP to automatic. Check BOL, in case I have the flag typed in incorrectly. I will have to mull over this a bit and determine if this is the only issue in the mix.